# PHP - Get Meta Tags

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php

$LF = 'links.txt';
$Rfp = fopen($LF, 'r');

while(!feof($Rfp))
{
    $links = fgets($Rfp);
    $tags = get_meta_tags($links);

    if ($tags['description'] == "")
        echo "No META Description Found";
    else
        echo $tags['description'];
}

fclose($Rfp);

?>
```

My links.txt has a list of 5000 URLS one per line. I get this error for every URL in my file, when I execute this script

```
Warning: get_meta_tags(http://www.1saleaday.com ) [function.get-meta-tags]: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in F:\xampp\htdocs\mte.php on line 10
No META Description Foundhttp://www.1stopflorists.com
Warning: get_meta_tags() [function.get-meta-tags]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in F:\xampp\htdocs\mte.php on line 10
```

I am sure that the links I have in my links.txt file, all have META description. So, where am I failing? Please guide.

Comment: Sounds more the problem is the PHP is having trouble fetching the page, rather than pages not having `meta` elements. Set up a script where PHP fetches (via `get_meta_tags`) any old [URL](http://google.com) and see if that works.

Comment: Yes. When I hardcode the URL as `$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.1saleaday.com');` it works fine. It fetches me the description "1 Sale A Day, 1 Great Deal Everyday, Daily Deal, Join" correctly. It is just when I try to read it line by line from a file using fgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Apparently, PHP is unable to load the page. Perhaps the links don't have the proper format?

A quick test shows that this happens when I try `get_meta_tags('http://domain.com http://another-domain.com');`, perhaps there is something wrong with the newlines?
(Windows vs Unix line-endings?)

Comment: May be you are correct. I am on Windows XP SP2. Now, how do I ensure that my line endings are correct?

Comment: Instead of `$tags = get_meta_tags($links);`, do `echo "Load URL: $links <br>";
$tags = get_meta_tags($links);
echo "<br>`

You should now see what URL is being loaded just before the error occures - if I'm right, it won't be one URL, but (at least) two.

Answer (score 4):

Here are my example which is working:
links.txt is looking like in this example

```
http://www.site1.com
http://www.site2.com
http://www.site2.com/page1
```

no space after each line and no break at the end of file

```
 <?php

$LF = 'links.txt';
$Rfp = fopen($LF, 'r');

while(!feof($Rfp))
{
    $links = fgets($Rfp);
    echo "<br>"; echo "<font color=\"red\">Load URL: $links </font>"; $tags = get_meta_tags($links); echo "<br>";

    if ($tags['description'] == "")
    echo "No META Description Found";
    else
        echo "<br>"; 
    echo "<b>Description</b> - "; 
    echo $tags['description']; 
    echo "<br>";

    if ($tags['keywords'] == "")
        echo "No META Keywords Found";
    else
        echo "<br>";
    echo "<b>Keywords</b> - ";
    echo $tags['keywords'];
    echo "<br>";
}

fclose($Rfp);

?>
```

the result look well and no errors

Answer (score 2):

The answer you need is right in the warning output you included...note the space after the URL:

Warning: get_meta_tags(http://www.example.com ) [function.get-meta-tags]

If you add:

$links = trim($links);

Your code will start working.