# PHP get meta tags function doesn't work with non http

Tags: php

I was hoping I can get help with a problem I am having.

I'm using the php get meta tags function to see if a tag exist on a list of websites, the problem occurs when ever there is a domain without HTTP.

Ideally I would want to add the HTTP if it doesn't exist, and also I would need a work around if the domain has HTTPS here is the code I'm using.

I will get this error if I land on a site without HTTP in the domain.

> Warning: get_meta_tags(www.drhugopavon.com/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\webresp\index.php on line 16

```
$urls = array(
    'https://www.smilesbycarroll.com/',
    'https://hurstbournedentalcare.com/',
    'https://www.dentalhc.com/',
    'https://www.springhurstdentistry.com/',
    'https://www.smilesbycarroll.com/',
    'www.drhugopavon.com/'
);

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $tags = get_meta_tags($url);

    if (isset($tags['viewport'])) {
        echo "$url tag exist" . "</br>";
    }

    if (!isset($tags['viewport'])) {
        echo "$url tag doesnt exist" . "</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Get Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656442/php-get-meta-tags)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to check if the domain has http

```
foreach($urls as $url){
  if(strpos($url, "http") === FALSE) //check if the url contains http and add it to the beginning of the string if it doesn't 
    $url = "http://" . $url;

  $tags = get_meta_tags($url);
}
```

Another simpler option would be to check for :// in the url

```
 foreach($urls as $url){
      if(strpos($url, "://") === FALSE) //check if the url contains http and add it to the beginning of the string if it doesn't 
        $url = "http://" . $url;

      $tags = get_meta_tags($url);
 }
```

Or you can use regex like  Wild Beard suggested

Comment: What about `www.http.com`?

Comment: it will skip it as it does contain http in the url string. I wil try tol expand my answer with another solution that might suit you better

Comment: `preg_match('/(^http)/', $url)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `parse_url()` to check if the element `scheme` exists or not. If not, you could add it:

```
$urls = array(
    'https://www.smilesbycarroll.com/',
    'https://hurstbournedentalcare.com/',
    'https://www.dentalhc.com/',
    'https://www.springhurstdentistry.com/',
    'https://www.smilesbycarroll.com/',
    'www.drhugopavon.com/'
);

$urls = array_map(function($url) {
  $data = parse_url($url);
  if (!isset($data['scheme'])) $url = 'http://' . $url ;
  return $url;
}, $urls);

print_r($urls);
```

Answer (score 0):

you know whats funny, I thought it was because it had http but I put    error_reporting(0); in my original code and it worked as I wanted it to haha.